# pyspark streaming and utils import issues

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am trying to run below code

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/opt/spark')
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.3.0 pyspark-shell'

import sys
import time
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

n_secs = 1
topic = "video-stream-event"
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaStreamProcessor").setMaster("local[*]")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, n_secs)
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {
                        'bootstrap.servers':'127.0.0.1  :9092', 
                        'group.id':'video-group', 
                        'fetch.message.max.bytes':'15728640',
                        'auto.offset.reset':'largest'})
#lines = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: x[1])
print(kafkastream)
```

---

I got the following error

> from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils ModuleNotFoundError:
> No module named 'pyspark.streaming.kafka' log4j:WARN No appenders
> could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Used python ==3.7 and pyspark ==3.1.2
changed to pyspark 2.4.5 and 2.4.6 and exdecuted the same code ,got the below error

```
> 21/10/18 14:05:47 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind
> to another address WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has
> occurred WARNING: Illegal reflective access by
> org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
> (file:/opt/spark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.11-2.4.5.jar) to method
> java.nio.Bits.unaligned() WARNING: Please consider reporting this to
> the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform WARNING: Use
> --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be
> denied in a future release 21/10/18 14:05:47 WARN NativeCodeLoader:
> Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using
> builtin-java classes where applicable Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "/home/deepika/Desktop/kafka/kafka_pyspark.py", line 12,
> in <module>
>     from pyspark.context import SparkContext   File "/home/deepika/Downloads/code_dump/spark/python/pyspark/__init__.py",
> line 51, in <module>
>     from pyspark.context import SparkContext   File "/home/deepika/Downloads/code_dump/spark/python/pyspark/context.py",
> line 31, in <module>
>     from pyspark import accumulators   File "/home/deepika/Downloads/code_dump/spark/python/pyspark/accumulators.py",
> line 97, in <module>
>     from pyspark.serializers import read_int, PickleSerializer   File "/home/deepika/Downloads/code_dump/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 72, in <module>
>     from pyspark import cloudpickle   File "/home/deepika/Downloads/code_dump/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
> line 145, in <module>
>     _cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()   File "/home/deepika/Downloads/code_dump/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
> line 126, in _make_cell_set_template_code
>     return types.CodeType( TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
> (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager). log4j:WARN Please
> initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
> http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Any idea what to do now?I want to run the above code.Tried python 3.7 and 3.8 and pysprk versions too ending with these 2 errors
INstalled pyspark with this link :

[Installation Link for pyspark](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/installing-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-20-04-or-18-04/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should use `spark-sql-kafka-0-10`
2. You need to move `findspark.init()` after `os.environ` line. Also, you don't actually need this line, as you can provide the packages via findspark.

```
SPARK_VERSION = '3.1.2'
SCALA_VERSION = '2.12'

import findspark
findspark.add_packages(['org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_' + SCALA_VERSION + ':' + SPARK_VERSION ])

findspark.init()
 
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
```

Also, if just getting started with Spark, use the latest version

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Regarding the log4j error, you need to create a `log4j.properties` file in `$SPARK_HOME/conf`